# 3d grayscale volume projection onto 2D plane

Tags: matlab, 3d, 2d, projection

I have a 3-D grayscale volume corresponding to ultrasound data. In Matlab this 3-D volume is simply a 3-D matrix of *MxNxP*. The structure I'm interested in is not oriented along the *z* axis, but along a local coordinate system already known (*x'y'z'*). What I have up to this point is something like the figure shown below, depicting the original (*xyz*) and the local coordinate systems (*x'y'z'*):

[image: abc]

I want to obtain the 2-D projection of this volume (i.e. an image) through a specific plane on the local coordinate system, say at *z' = z0*. How can I do this?

If the volume was oriented along the *z* axis this projection could be readily achieved. i.e. if the volume, in Matlab, is *V*, then:

```
projection = sum(V,3);
```

thus, the projection can be computed just as the sum along the 3rd dimension of the array. However with a change of orientation the problem becomes more complicated.

I've been looking at radon transform (2D, that applies only to 2-D images and not volumes) and also been considering ortographic projections, but at this point I'm clueless as to what to do!

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Up to this point I'm trying the approach described in [this blog (Matlab's Steve on Image Processing)](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/08/17/spatial-transformations-three-dimensional-rotation/) making use of 3-D affine transformations. However I'm still missing one bit: how to define the angle(s) in the rotation matrix based on my orthonormal basis vectors x' y' z'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New attempt at solution:

Following the tutorial http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/08/17/spatial-transformations-three-dimensional-rotation/ and making some small changes, I might have something which could help you. Bear in mind, I have little or no experience with volumetric data in MATLAB, so the implementation is quite hacky.

In the below code I use tformarray() to rotate the structure in space. First, the data is centered, then rotated using rotationmat3D to produce the spacial transformation, before the data is moved back to its original position.

As I have never used tformarray before, I handeled datapoints falling outside the defined region after rotation by simply padding the data matrix (NxMxP) with zeros all around. If anyone know a better way, please let us know :)

The code:

```
    %Synthetic dataset, 25x50x25
blob = flow();

%Pad to allow for rotations in space. Bad solution, 
%something better might be possible to better understanding
%of tformarray()
blob = padarray(blob,size(blob));

f1 = figure(1);clf;
s1=subplot(1,2,1);
p = patch(isosurface(blob,1));
set(p, 'FaceColor', 'red', 'EdgeColor', 'none');
daspect([1 1 1]);
view([1 1 1])
camlight
lighting gouraud

%Calculate center
blob_center = (size(blob) + 1) / 2;

%Translate to origin transformation
T1 = [1 0 0 0
    0 1 0 0
    0 0 1 0
    -blob_center 1];

%Rotation around [0 0 1]
rot = -pi/3;
Rot = rotationmat3D(rot,[0 1 1]);
T2 = [ 1  0  0   0
       0  1  0   0
       0  0  1   0
       0  0  0   1];
T2(1:3,1:3) = Rot;   

%Translation back
T3 = [1 0 0 0
    0 1 0 0
    0 0 1 0
    blob_center 1];

%Total transform
T = T1 * T2 * T3;

%See http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/08/17/spatial-transformations-three-dimensional-rotation/
tform = maketform('affine', T);
R = makeresampler('linear', 'fill');
TDIMS_A = [1 2 3];
TDIMS_B = [1 2 3];
TSIZE_B = size(blob);
TMAP_B = [];
F = 0;
blob2 = ...
tformarray(blob, tform, R, TDIMS_A, TDIMS_B, TSIZE_B, TMAP_B, F);

s2=subplot(1,2,2);
p2 = patch(isosurface(blob2,1));
set(p2, 'FaceColor', 'red', 'EdgeColor', 'none');
daspect([1 1 1]);
view([1 1 1])
camlight
lighting gouraud
```

The arbitrary visualization below is just to confirm that the data is rotated as expected, plotting a closed surface when the data passed the value '1'. With blob2, you should know be able to project by using simple sums.

```
figure(2)
subplot(1,2,1);imagesc(sum(blob,3));
subplot(1,2,2);imagesc(sum(blob2,3));
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Vidar! This is actually the approach I'm considering at this point (see my comment above in my question)... However one aspect remains unclear: in my case I do not know the rotation angle (which in your case is -pi/3 on matrix T2 of the affine transformation), what I have is the orthonormal basis x',y',z'. I think this rotation angle might depend on the relative angles between z' and z axes, but I haven't figured it out yet! What could be the form of the rotation matrix in this case?... Thanks!

Comment: I think if you just replace my "Rot" matrix with your orthonormal basis, it should do the trick. Keep in mind that my Rot actually is a orthonormal basis: Rot(:,i)'*Rot(:,j) = 0 for all i not equal to j, and =1 for i=j.

Comment: Yes, so the columns on the "Rot" matrix will be each one of the vectors in the orthonormal basis. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to the coordinate basis R=[x' y' z'], and that those vectors are orthonormal, you can simply extract the representation in this basis by multiplying your data with the the 3x3 matrix R, where x',y',z' are column vectors.

With the data stored in D (Nx3), you can get the representation with R, by multiplying by it:
    Dmarked = D*R;

and now D = Dmarked*inv(R), so going back and forth is stragihtforward.

The following code might provide help to see the transformation. Here I create a synthetic dataset, rotate it, and then rotate it back. Doing sum(DR(:,3)) would then be your sum along z'

```
%#Create synthetic dataset
N1 = 250;
r1 = 1;
dr1 = 0.1;
dz1 = 0;
mu1 = [0;0];
Sigma1 = eye(2);
theta1 = 0 + (2*pi).*rand(N1,1);
rRand1 = normrnd(r1,dr1,1,N1);
rZ1 = rand(N1,1)*dz1+1;
D = [([rZ1*0 rZ1*0] + repmat(rRand1',1,2)).*[sin(theta1) cos(theta1)] rZ1];

%Create roation matrix
rot = pi/8;
R = rotationmat3D(rot,[0 1 0]);
% R =       0.9239          0       0.3827
%           0               1.0000  0
%           -0.3827         0       0.9239

Rinv = inv(R);

%Rotate data
DR = D*R;

%#Visaulize data
f1 = figure(1);clf
subplot(1,3,1);
plot3(DR(:,1),DR(:,2),DR(:,3),'.');title('Your data')
subplot(1,3,2);
plot3(DR*Rinv(:,1),DR*Rinv(:,2),DR*Rinv(:,3),'.r');
view([0.5 0.5 0.2]);title('Representation using your [xmarked ymarked zmarked]');
subplot(1,3,3);
plot3(D(:,1),D(:,2),D(:,3),'.');
view([0.5 0.5 0.2]);title('Original data before rotation');
```

[image]

Comment: I have a few questions: (i) Why data vector _D_ is Nx3? In my case data refers to the gray levels of each voxel, and so for a volume of MxNxP I have M.N.P data points, not Nx3; (ii) The representation of the data in the basis (i.e. Dmarked = D*R) isn't actually the representation of points' coordinates (x,y,z) of D onto the basis [x' y' z']? (iii) What does the "rotationmat3D" function stands for? Where can I find it?... Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I guess I didnt understand the structure of your data then. You are working with evenly spaced samples of a space, with M points in width, N in depth and P in height?

Rotmat3D can be found here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23417-compute-3d-rotation-matrix

Comment: Yes indeed, I'm working with evenly spaced samples: M voxels width, N in depth and P in height

Comment: Please see my new answer below. Should I just delete the previous one?

Answer (score 0):

If you have two **normalized** 3x1 vectors `x2` and `y2` corresponding to your local coordinate system (x' and y').

Then, for a position `P`, its local coordinate will be `xP=P'x2` and `yP=P'*y2`.

So you can try to project your volume using accumarray:

```
[x y z]=ndgrid(1:M,1:N,1:P);
posP=[x(:) y(:) z(:)];
xP=round(posP*x2);
yP=round(posP*y2);
xP=xP+min(xP(:))+1;
yP=yP+min(yP(:))+1;
V2=accumarray([xP(:),yP(:)],V(:));
```

If you provide your data, I will test it.

Comment: The problem in this case is that when obtaining the local coordinates xP and yP, sometimes these subindices are out of bounds (i.e. are negative, zero or not contained in the volume). As an example:  

`V = randn(200,100,50);    %Synthetic volume`  
`[M,N,P] = size(V);`  
`[x,y,z] = meshgrid(1:N,1:M,1:P);`  
`x2 = [0.7071 0.7071 -0.0035]';   %Basis vector in x' direction`  
`y2 = [-0.6869 0.6857 -0.2410]';   %Basis vector in y' direction`  

When using this data yP values are out of bonds (beyond the limits of my 200x100x50 volume)

Comment: I put the lines: `xP=xP+min(xP(:))+1;yP=yP+min(yP(:))+1;` to handle values below zeros. If you really want bounds you can do something like: `inds= xP>lowX & xP<highX & yP>lowY & yP<highY; xP=xP(inds);yP=yP(inds);V=V(inds);`